# Длина минимального слова

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток. Можете ли помочь найти длину самого минимального слова в строке  
 разделенной пробелами на Java.

Comment: Так на Java или Javascript?

Comment: ой, ссори=) на Java.

Comment: @Andrey2517, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так на Java

```
    String x="sdfds ds dsfsdf  sdfs   sdf sdf";
    String[] xx=x.split(" ");
    int min=1000000;
    for (String i: xx){
        if (i.length()>0 && i.length()<min) min=i.length();
    }
```

P.S. Мини-реклама Python

```
x="sdfds ds dsfsdf  sdfs   sdf sdf"
minlen=min(map(len, filter(lambda y: y!='', x.split(' '))))
```

Comment: че сказать, питон - крут!

Comment: Питон - охренительный язык программирования...он даже больше, чем просто язык.....

Comment: @ReinRaus, объясните популярно **каким образом после split может появиться ПУСТОЕ слово ?**. 

Это я про i.length()>0 .

Comment: @avp, а вы всегда уверены, что `split` несколько подряд идущих пробелов опускает?

Comment: да какая разница, препод тройку поставил и ладно

Comment: Если честно, не помню тонкостей работы отдельных языков, но вот например Python:  

    >>> x='sdfds ds dsfsdf  sdfs   sdf sdf'
    >>> x.split(" ")
    ['sdfds', 'ds', 'dsfsdf', '', 'sdfs', '', '', 'sdf', 'sdf']
Проще перестраховаться, даже когда пишешь на Java или любом другом языке.

Comment: Пардон, ошибся. Конечно надо .split(" +");

Comment: @avp согласен

Comment: а если точка? наверное, лучше использовать Tokenizer

Comment: `"split,тащем-та,разбивает_по_регулярному_выражению"`

Comment: ну вообще если использовать лямбды в джаве, получится почти так же как и в питоне

Comment: хм. когда писался этот ответ в джаве лямбд небыло)))

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
function find_min(str)
{
    str=str.replace(/,/g, "");
    arr = str.split(' ');
    max_len = 0;
    for(i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++)
    if(arr[i].length>max_len) {newstr=arr[i]; max_len=arr[i].length;}
    return newstr;
    }

alert(find_min("Yesterday, all my troubffffffles seemed so far away Now it looks as though they're here to stay Oh, I believe in yesterday."));

</script>
```

**Блин, так ведь сначала нужна была реализация на JS ! Тьфу)**

Comment: извиняюсь) моя ошибка

Comment: Ничего, я уже привык =)

Answer (score 1):

ИМХО, современный C# (3.0 и выше) ничем не уступает Пайтону по красоте и выразительности.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine().Split()
            .OrderBy(x => x.Length).LastOrDefault());

        // можно еще так, вроде выглядит попроще, но работает медленнее

        Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine().Split().Max(x => x.Length));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ловите студонята.. Писал 20 хв с вышеуказанным примером (лабораторная), макс и мин число..

> ```
> package qq;
>
> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> public class alln {
>   public static void main(String[] args){
>    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
>    String x=sc.nextLine();
>    sc.close();
>
>    //String x="sdfds ds dsfsdf ds sdfs sdf sdf";
>    String[] xx=x.split(" ");
>      int min = 1000000;
>      int max = 0;
>
>      int bufmin = 0;
>      int bufmax = 0;
>
>      String temp;
>      String tempz;
>
>     for(int i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
>       temp = xx[i];
>       if (temp.length()<min){
>           min=temp.length();
>           bufmin=i;
>       }
>     }
>
>     for(int i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
>       tempz = xx[i];
>       if (tempz.length()>max){
>           max=tempz.length();
>           bufmax=i;
>       }
>     }
>
>       System.out.print("Min: "+min+" ("+xx[bufmin]+") ; Max: "+max+"
> ```
>
> ("+xx[bufmax]+") ;");
>
> ```
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Я бы поставил двойку.
1. Что будет, если в массиве будет строка длиннее миллиона символов?
2. Что будет, если в массиве будет строка нулевой длины?
3. Два прохода!
4. Конкатенация строк!

Comment: Ну крОсавец ты.. Говорю - писал за 20 мин, и совсем не думал об этом, ибо мне - как быстрее написать. Кто хочет - допилит. Дописать твои ф-ции - еще минут 10,но оно мне нах не надо. Кинул как начальный пример, дальше дело твое - пили хоть парсер дойки.ком
==============
Твои слова ограничиваются лишь if (arr.length)

Comment: Думать надо всегда. Особенно при написании таких маленьких примерчиков. Или ты думал, кому-то сильно интересно, как ты реализуешь сам принцип? Там-то вариантов как раз немного, и все давно придуманы. Я много вижу кода от людей с такой мотивацией (как быстрее написать). Правда заключается в том, что в промышленном программировании не особо кому интересна скорость. Профессиональный программист пишет в среднем 10 строк в день. Важна архитектура этих строк, их "вылизанность" до идеала. Олимпиадники в нормальных конторах не нужны, они предпочтут нанять обучаемого "незнайку", чем "знайку" с гонором

Comment: > Говорю - писал за 20 мин

---

> Правда заключается в том, что в промышленном программировании не особо кому интересна скорость.

я даже не знаю, что меня вгоняет в печаль больше - то, что кто-то считает, что двадцать минут на эту задачу - это мало, или то, что кто-то считает, что олимпиадник - это курица, обученная быстро махать лапами, и в реальности эти навыки абсолютно неприменимы.

Comment: Впрочем, понял: больше всего меня печалит то, что вопросу три года.

Comment: Не принимайте на свой счет, я же говорю о тенденции. Есть такая порода "олимпиадников" (название чисто условное, такой человек мог ни разу в жизни не принимать участия в олимпиадах), которые думают, что их способность наговнокодить несколько сотен строк за несколько десятков минут (реально видел) кому-то нужна. "А че, работает же!"

А потом он рассуждает о том, что везде блат, везде еврейская (чеченская, голубая) мафия, поэтому его и не берут на работу.

Бизнес прост и жесток: там делают то, что выгодно. Но признаваться, что проблема в том, что ты менее выгоден, чем "незнайка", так неохота...

Comment: @VadimTukaev, я знаю, что разница (по куче показателей) на порядок для людей не редкость, но 10 строк в день -- это наверное среднее за *все время работы в данной организации* (с учетом всех простоев, обучения и т.д.)?

--

@Makovyak, если уж собрались учить, то может лучше начать так:

     ...
     int min = 0, max = 0, bufmin = 0, bufmax = 0; // или в Java можно не обнулять?
     if (xx.length() > 0) {
       min = xx[0].length();
       max = min;
       for (i = 1; i < xx.length(); i++) { // перебор именно  с 1 !!!
          ....

Comment: @VadimTukaev, по-моему у вас просто тоже болит сердце из-за того, что вы, как и я, в школьно-студенческие годы никуда не ездили.

Comment: @avp, можно не обнулять http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

Comment: @Etki: Ездил один раз - очень неудачно. :) На зависть хотите все списать? А если я скажу, что есть такая порода людей, которая до сих пор считает землю плоской, то это, конечно, я завидую им, ибо атеист.

@avp: Не знаю, откуда взялась байка конкретно про 10 строк, но подозреваю, что считались только те строки, которые прошли тесты. Можно же неделю писать по 100 строк в день, а потом догадаться, как эту функцию написать нормально. И она получилась 7 строк длиной. Вот вам одна строка в день. К тому же учтите, что далеко не все языки столь многословны, как Java. На Factor строка в день - неплохо